# DELETE complete column from table

Tags: sql

```
[Name] [major_version] [minor_version] [revision] [install_failures]

   s       23                1            NULL           0
```

This is my table. How can I delete the `revision` column (not the value, the complete revision column) from table?

Comment: What server are you using? MySql? Sql server?

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: Have you tried to find this out ???

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` DROP COLUMN `revision`;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the following sql

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP COLUMN revision
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) can you read simple documentation on that.

Answer (score 2):

Use ALTER statement

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN revision;
```

> The ALTER TABLE statement is used to
>   add, delete, or modify columns in an
>   existing table.

Syntax :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP COLUMN column_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `alter table` statement to delete the `revision` column from your table.

> The ALTER TABLE statement is used to
>   add, delete, or modify columns in an
>   existing table.

your delete column syntax will look like this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP COLUMN revision
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple...use this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name
```

Here are some links that will help you.

[techonthenet](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/alter_table.php), [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp), [php.about](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/drop_column.htm), [sqlzoo](http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/z.dir/tip550065/sqlserver).